# VBA Code for filtering a column using Input Box

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm looking to filter a column based on a code the user puts into an input box.

I used the following code:

```
Sub Filter()
'
' Filter Macro
Dim strName As String
strName = InputBox(“What DMA would you like to search for?”)
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AS$355969").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="=*" & strName & “ * ”, Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

But it shows compile error:

> Syntax error in Excel Macro

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Wrong quote symbols in InputBox arg. Replace them with double-quotes `"`.

Comment: Yes, spot the mix of double quote types “ and "

Comment: Hey Guys, thanks for spotting the error. Now the issue is the InputBox is visible by running the macro, but the filtered data is not shown. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume you want wildcard matching so you do not need the additional white space in the second wildcard. In addition you need correct "" and switching off ScreenUpdating is a good idea. You can also use a With statememt for your range. Better would be to use an explicit sheet name rather than Activesheet in case the current Activesheet is not the one you were expecting.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Filter()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strName As String
    strName = InputBox("What DMA would you like to search for?")
    With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AS$355969")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*" & strName & "*"
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the coding. but still its not working. It just shows filtered option in the 3rd column, but is not showing the filtered values. I have some blank spaces here and there in the active sheet range. Will that cause any issUe?

Comment: Do you have a header in A1? Can you show a small sample of the first 5 columns with expected filter in place (including row 1 in the data/image)?

Comment: Yea I do have a Header in A1. I actually don't know how to add the image in this comment.

Answer (score 1):

*You may try this simple code to filter:*

```
Sub InputFilter()
Dim strInput As String
strInput = InputBox("Enter your value to filter on")
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$60:$A$65").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=strInput
End Sub
```

**N.B.** Remember `Field` value in the code is adjustable if the Criteria matches the Column 2 to filter then it should be `Field:=2`

**Note,** *adjust cell references as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

A very useful tutorial.

More advanced filtering can be achieved by adding a textbox control to the worksheet.

I created a template to filter on the worksheet based on the searched value (letters, numbers or other characters) in textbox , using the VBA Find and AutoFilter methods.
The filtered cells are listed on the worksheet, the number of filtered cells is informed to the user by msgbox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ79i.gif)

I hope it benefits to users.

I created the template using the VBA find and findnext methods in the do - while loop :

```
...
Sheets("Data").Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
 
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        Set bCell = aCell
        Range("AN2").Value = aCell.Address(False, False)
        Do
        son = 0
            Set aCell = Range("F4:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).FindNext(After:=aCell)
         If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
           If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
      son = son + 1
    Range("AN" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(son, 0).Value = aCell.Address(False, False)
        Else
                Exit Do
           End If
        Loop
 Label1.Visible = False
    Else
    Label1.Visible = False
    Range("G2").Activate
    MsgBox SearchString & " Not Found", vbCritical, ""
    Exit Sub
    End If
...
```

[For all codes and sample file source](https://eksi30.com/searching-data-in-a-worksheet-using-vba-find-autofilter-methods/)