# VBA Code for multiple filter inputs in a single column using single input Box

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need to filter my excel using a macro (multiple data)

[image]

I like to Filter "the grade column" (as in image) with A, B and C (but these A,B & C are not constrained, sometimes i only need "B and C" grade data ) & i like to input these grades for filter using a inputbox.

Can any one help me on the code

If the input can be given as "A+B+C" or as "A B C" it will be greatly helpful

Here are the sample data, space separated:

> ```
> Name class Grade
> Liam 1 A
> Noah 2 b
> William 3 c
> James 1 d
> Olive 2 e
> Benjamin 3 f
> Elijah 1 A
> Lucas 2 b
> Mason 3 c
> Logan 1 d
> Alexander 2 e
> Ethan 3 f
> Jacob 1 A
> Michael 2 b
> Daniel 3 c
> Henry 1 d
> Jackson 2 e
> Sebastian 3 f
> Aiden 1 A
> Emma 2 b
> Olivia 3 c
> Ava 1 d
> Isabella 2 e
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Super User, earlier I've posted VBA code for similar issue,,,  [Just Check This Link](https://superuser.com/questions/1352909/vba-code-for-filtering-a-column-using-input-box) ,,, and adjust Filter Column's Data Range as your need ☺

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you don't want to use the Autofilter drop-down to filter the data. Instead you want to type a list of items into an InputBox and then filter the data on those items.

You can do that with this code:

```
Sub FilterListUsingInputBox()
    
    Dim sep As String
    Dim filter As String
    Dim filters() As String
    
    sep = " "
    
    filter = InputBox("Enter a list of 1-n filter items, separated by a space")
    
    If filter = "" Then 'no filter was entered
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    filters = Split(filter, sep)
    
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=filters, Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

What's important to note here is that you must first split the input into an array with `Split()` then pass that to the `Range.AutoFilter` method while also specifying `Operator:=xlFilterValues`.

This assumes that:

1. Your data are in the range that includes the cell A1. If not, change the last line in the procedure.
2. Your data are on Sheet1. If not, change the last line in the procedure.
3. You want to use a space to separate the list items. If not, change the line that says `sep = " "` to something else.

Comment: Thanks a lot.... works great and grateful for a quick reply.

Comment: I tried using "+" as a separator but it doesn't work any idea, why?

Comment: If you want to use + as the separator, change the line to `sep = "+"`

Comment: @FlexYourData,,, is good one +10 ☺

Comment: Thanks, It havent worked when i changed " Sep ="+" " but worked when i changed the delimiter in filters formula " filters = Split(filter, "+") "

Comment: Oh! My mistake. Needs to be `filters = Split(filter,sep)`. I've corrected the code in my answer.